# XSLT FO program, XML data structuring issue into PDF

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I am new to XSLT and had a requirement to convert an XML file to PDF. I have a JAVA program that converts the XML to PDF using an XSLT FO file.

Below is my XML.

```
<PDFReport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Type>ABC</Type>
<Number>001</Number>
<CustomerDetails>
  <Country>USA</Country>
  <Name>John Doe</Name>
</CustomerDetails>
<PurchasedGoods>Category A</PurchasedGoods>
<Amount>123456</Amount>
<CustomerDetails>
  <Country>China</Country>
  <Name>Stuart Lim</Name>
</CustomerDetails>
<PurchasedGoods>Category B</PurchasedGoods>
<Amount>987654</Amount>
</PDFReport>
```

I am using the below XSLT file to transform to an XML file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simple" margin="0.5in">
                <fo:region-body/>
              </fo:simple-page-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simple">
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PDFReport">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./Type"/> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./Number"/> 
    <xsl:for-each select="./CustomerDetails">        
           <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>   
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./PurchasedGoods"/> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./Amount"/> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Type">
    <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Arial">
         <fo:block>Type :  <xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
    </fo:block>  
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Number">
    <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Arial">
         <fo:block>Number :  <xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
    </fo:block>  
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Country">
    <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Arial">
         <fo:block>Country :  <xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
    </fo:block>  
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Name">
    <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Arial">
         <fo:block>Name :  <xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
    </fo:block>  
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="PurchasedGoods">
    <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Arial">
         <fo:block>Purchased Goods :  <xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
    </fo:block>  
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="Amount">
    <fo:block text-align="left" font-family="Arial">
         <fo:block>Amount :  <xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
    </fo:block>  
 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting the PDF output as follows

```
Type : ABC
Number : 001
Country : USA
Name : John Doe
Country : China
Name : Stuart Lim
Purchased Goods : Category A
Purchased Goods : Category B
Amount : 123456
Amount : 987654
```

But, I want the output as follows.

```
Type : ABC
Number : 001

Country : USA
Name : John Doe
Purchased Goods : Category A
Amount : 123456

Country : China
Name : Stuart Lim
Purchased Goods : Category B
Amount : 987654
```

Can the above be done without changing the XML structure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting your current result because you are directing that the elements are processed in that order in your sequence of `xsl:apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:template match="PDFReport">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./Type"/> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./Number"/> 
    <xsl:for-each select="./CustomerDetails">        
           <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>   
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./PurchasedGoods"/> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./Amount"/> 
</xsl:template>
```

Firstly, you can let the structure of the source document define the order in which the elements are processed simply by removing the template for `PDFReport`.

In XSLT, just `<xsl:apply-templates />` (as in your template for `\`) selects all of the child nodes and applies templates to them. The effect of the built-in default templates for the different node types means that element nodes that don't have a template in your stylesheet just do `<xsl:apply-templates />` on their child nodes without themselves adding anything to the result. With the built-in default templates, it's only text nodes that end up copied into the result tree. Which is a long way of saying that removing the template for `PDFReport` will result in `Type`, `Number`, `CustomerDetails`, etc., being processed in the order in which they appear in the source document.

Secondly, to get some space before the customer details, add a template for `CustomerDetails` with an `fo:block` that specifies a `space-before` value (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#space-before):

```
<xsl:template match="CustomerDetails">
  <fo:block space-before="1em">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

This `<xsl:apply-templates />` will process the child nodes of `CustomerDetails` in their document order. (Without a template for `CustomerDetails` in the stylesheet that you showed, that's what was happening anyway.)

Alternatively, you could just specify `space-before` on the `fo:block` for `Country` if `Country` is always the first child of `CustomerDetails`.